# ActiveAdmin error - undefined method `action_methods' for "admin/admin_users":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

Getting the following error upon navigating to the ActiveAdmin resource for admin_users:

```
undefined method `action_methods' for "admin/admin_users":String
```

First few lines of trace:

```
activeadmin (0.3.2) lib/active_admin/resource/action_items.rb:51:in `block in add_default_action_items'
activeadmin (0.3.2) lib/active_admin/views/action_items.rb:9:in `instance_eval'
activeadmin (0.3.2) lib/active_admin/views/action_items.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in build'
activeadmin (0.3.2) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:68:in `block in build_tag'
activeadmin (0.3.2) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:96:in `with_current_dom_context'
activeadmin (0.3.2) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:67:in `build_tag'
activeadmin (0.3.2) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:77:in `insert_tag'
activeadmin (0.3.2) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/element.rb:17:in `span'
```

I've basically just followed the steps outlined in: http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin?view=asciicast

Answer (score 4):

Found the problem. Had an instance variable named @controller in application_controller.rb. Lesson learned... never use reserved keywords for variables.